# Rogue moving to chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

My answer https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/7349/6346 did not have a long discussion iirc, but someone moved it to chat. Except that it seems to go to a totally inappropriate chat. The same has happened with other answer on the same question.

The user name who did the moving is not one I recognize, and it looks suspicious no matter what.

Can someone with more meta foo than me take a look what's going on here?

Comment: I think that user was trolling and just manually posting a comment that looks like an automatic system message, while no actual comments were removed. You might want to flag it for a mod's attention.

Comment: Or, if I have to very assume good faith, the user was testing something about the URL format. [They posted 18 comments](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/users/12078/not-cseducator?tab=activity&sort=comments) with a slight variation of the chat room ID and URL slug.

Comment: Off-topic, but I don't know how else to ask you. Would you like to run for moderator [election on CompSci SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/election/3)? I think you will be a better candidate than most others, and I wouldn't want to see a lousy one get elected just because nobody else ran for election. What do you think? =)

Comment: @user21820 One does wish that SE had a way of messaging people, not? Eh, thanks for asking, but my day is full enough already. I'll decline taking this upon me.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for the reply and all the best! =)

Answer (score 8):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention!

Comments can be moved to chat for a couple reasons, either because a moderator manually moved them to chat, or after an exchange that meets specific criteria a non-moderator may be prompted to move them to chat. However, without any prior discussion, it is not possible for a non-moderator to move comments to chat.

When you see something strange like this, it's best to flag it (using a custom reason and describing what you see) so that we can look into it!

Comment: Two more such wrong moves
- https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/7280/8837
- https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/7268/8837

Comment: Happened again just now, seems they are testing in production again (or whatever they're doing): https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/users/12078/not-cseducator?tab=activity&sort=comments